# Vertex Displacement Distortion Correction

Tags: shaders, vertex, virtual-reality, displacement-mapping

I am developing for Mobile VR using GoogleVRSDK and Unity. My target platform is Android. 
I have a shader which displaces vertices to create a reverse lens distortion.

Following is my shader,

```
Shader "Unlit/Cube"
{

Properties {
    _Color("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
}

Category {

    Tags { "Queue"="Geometry" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Opaque" }

    Blend Off
    AlphaTest off
    Cull off
    Lighting Off
    ZWrite On
    ZTest LEqual
    Fog { Mode Off }

    SubShader {
        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM

           // #pragma target 3.5
           // #pragma target 2.0
           // #pragma only_renderers gles2
           // #pragma only_renderers gles

            #pragma vertex VertexProgram
            #pragma fragment FragmentProgram
            #pragma multi_compile __ GVR_DISTORTION
            #include "GvrDistortion.cginc"

            struct VertexInput {
                half4 vertex : POSITION;
                half4 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };



            struct v2f {
                half4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                half4 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            v2f VertexProgram (VertexInput v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.uv = v.texcoord;
                o.vertex = undistortVertex(v.vertex);
                return o;
            };

            fixed4 _Color;

            fixed4 FragmentProgram (v2f fragment) : COLOR
            {
                return _Color;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Following is my GvrDistortion.cginc

```
#if defined(GVR_DISTORTION)

float4x4  _Undistortion;
float     _MaxRadSq;
float     _NearClip;
float4x4  _RealProjection;
float4x4  _FixProjection;

float distortionFactor(float rSquared) {
  float ret = 0.0;
  ret = rSquared * (ret + _Undistortion[1][1]);
  ret = rSquared * (ret + _Undistortion[0][1]);
  ret = rSquared * (ret + _Undistortion[3][0]);
  ret = rSquared * (ret + _Undistortion[2][0]);
  ret = rSquared * (ret + _Undistortion[1][0]);
  ret = rSquared * (ret + _Undistortion[0][0]);
  return ret + 1.0;
} 

// Convert point from world space to undistorted camera space.
float4 undistort(float4 pos) {
  // Go to camera space.
  pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MV, pos);
  if (pos.z <= -_NearClip) {  // Reminder: Forward is -Z.
    // Undistort the point's coordinates in XY.
    float r2 = clamp(dot(pos.xy, pos.xy) / (pos.z*pos.z), 0,     _MaxRadSq);
    pos.xy *= distortionFactor(r2);
  }
  return pos;
}

// Multiply by no-lens projection matrix after undistortion.
float4 undistortVertex(float4 pos) {
  return mul(_RealProjection, undistort(pos));
}

// Surface shader hides away the MVP multiplication, so we have
// to multiply by _FixProjection = inverse(VP)*_RealProjection
// and then by inverse(M), in order to cancel it out and leave our
// own transform in place.
float4 undistortSurface(float4 pos) {
  float4 proj = mul(_FixProjection, undistort(pos));
  return mul(unity_WorldToObject, proj);
}

#else
// Distortion disabled.



// Just do the standard MVP transform.
float4 undistortVertex(float4 pos) {

 return mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, pos);
}

// Surface shader hides away the MVP multiplication, so just return   pos.
float4 undistortSurface(float4 pos) {

  return pos;
}

#endif
```

This shader works completely as excepted in Samsung S6 and LG G3 and the Unity Editor.

But we are working for a phone named Venus. In that phone shader renders but the displacement of vertices doesn't happen.

I tried disabling conditional compiling. 
I tried changing render targets and forcing different OpenGL versions in render.

Nothing worked. 
I would love to hear a solution. Thank you.

The specs of the Venus,

GPU Adreno(TM) 405
Runs OpenGL ES 3.0
GPU SM:4.0 and VRAM 512MB
RM 2gigs
Screen 1080x1920 60hz  dpi 480
Android 5.1 API-22
CPU is ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON (8 cores)

The shader in LG G3 :
[image]
The shader in Venus : 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that it is not preferred to answer my own question but i think it will be maybe useful to some people.

I forgot to update this post.

After long hours. The problem resolved.

It is the case of bad GLES drivers i guess.

Even if the phone says that it uses **GLES 3.0**,

forcing to use **GLES 2.0** in player settings worked.

If you ever stumble any non-standart phone try that first.

Comment: It is totally ok to answer your question. You should also mark it as solved when you can.